# How to reference function more directly?

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces

List directory `analyse` structure as below:

```
tree analyse
analyse
├── __init__.py
└── vix.py
```

The `__init__.py` is blank,`vix.py` contains a function `draw_vix`.

```
import analyse
analyse.vix.draw_vix()
```

`draw_vix` is referenced with  `analyse.vix.`,i want to reference it with `vix` instead of `analyse.vix`,that is to say ,to add `vix` in namespace after `import analyse`.
Edit `__init__.py`:

```
import analyse.vix as vix
from analyse import vix
```

Have a check:

```
import analyse
vix.draw_vix()
```

An error message:

```
NameError: name 'vix' is not defined
```

@hl037_,if i add `from .vix import vix` in `__init__.py`,

```
import analyse
vix.draw_vix()
```

It pose other issue: ImportError: cannot import name 'vix'.
What i want is to write something in `__init__.py` ,or to write someting in `vix.py` ,to make `vix.draw_vix()` take effect.
How to fix it?

Comment: I edited my answer with some examples

Comment: @scrapy, I added overloading of `__import__` builtin to ensure that the trick always work.

Comment: What is the problem with `from analyse import vix` and `import analyse`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> add vix in namespace after import analyse

By default the top-level scope is not visible in modules. `globals` function in modules returns module-level scope, not the scope of the importing module (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)). Therefore some tricks are required to put `vix` to external scope.

Trick one.

`import` statement in Python is actually a function call, and the code from `__init__.py` is executed whithin some stack frame. The trick is to find the stack frame that corresponds to the importing module and **pollute** it's scope. While this is possible, it is a BAD, BAD practice. It contradics the paradigm of Python, where simple things must be simple. If you need `vix` in the top-level scope, use `import analyse.vix as vix`. Scope pollution might result in names conflict and very subtle bugs.

Trick two.

Code from `__init__.py` is executed only once, during the first load of the package. In all other `import analyse` statements python interpreter uses the module object cached in `sys.modules`. The only way that I found is to intercept the calls to the `__import__` builtin and add scope polluting hooks.

**I strongly recommend avoiding this 'magic'**. Nevertheless, if you want to shoot in the foot, here it is.

Place the following code in `analyse/__init__.py`:

```py
from . import vix # create module "vix" in the current scope

import inspect as _inspect

# Inject `vix` at the first import
_frame = _inspect.currentframe().f_back
while _frame is not None:
    # skip Pyhton module loader
    if "importlib._bootstrap" in _frame.f_code.co_filename:
        _frame = _frame.f_back
        continue
    #this frame corresponds to the scope, where `import analyse` is specified
    _frame.f_globals["vix"] = vix # bind the name 'vix' with the module 'vix' from the current scope
    print("DEBUG: injected vix to ", _frame)
    break
# remove _frame from the scope
del[_frame]

# overload __import__ function to inject `vix` on every succeeding import of `analyse`
import builtins as _builtins
# save builtin that `import` calls
_builtin_import = _builtins.__import__ 

def _never_overload_import(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0):
    "This function injects `vix` in every scope that imports `analyse` module"
    global _builtin_import
    global vix
    result = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    if name == "analyse" and globals is not None and not "vix" in globals:
        globals["vix"] = vix
        print("DEBUG: injected vix to ", _inspect.currentframe().f_back)
    return result

_builtins.__import__ = _never_overload_import
```

This is how I tested:

1. file `secondary.py` just loads the target module.

```py
import analyse
# demonstrate that first import created `vix` at this scope
vix.draw_vix("called from secondary as `vix.draw_vix`")
```

2. file `test.py` loads both `secondary.py` and `analyse`

```py
print("***Loading secondary***")
import secondary
print("***Secondary loaded***")

print("***Loading analyse***")
import analyse
print("***Analyse loaded***")

analyse.vix.draw_vix("called as `analyse.vix.draw_vix`")
vix.draw_vix("called as `vix.draw_vix`")
```

The output:

```
***Loading secondary***
DEBUG: injected vix to  <frame at 0x00909AE8, file 'secondary.py', line 1, code <module>>
draw vix,  called from secondary as `vix.draw_vix`
***Secondary loaded***
***Loading analyse***
DEBUG: injected vix to  <frame at 0x00911C30, file 'test.py', line 6, code <module>>
***Analyse loaded***
draw vix,  called as `analyse.vix.draw_vix`
draw vix,  called as `vix.draw_vix`
```

**CHANGELOG**

*Added overloading `__import__` function*. The original answer just inserted `vix` object to the globals of the importing scope, but this is not enough: code in `__init__.py` is executed only once, during the first load of the package. When the package is imported in another file, it will see no `vix` module since the injection code is not executed.

Comment: This trick won't work if the module is already imported, because the traceback hack won't be called again since python don't reload modules by default. And only the first module to import it will get vix in the global scope

Comment: @hl037_, thanks for the point. I updated the answer: overloaded `__import__` builtin to inject `vix` in every scope that loads the target module.

Answer (score 5):

You just can't like this.

```
import analyse
```

will only make `analyse` in your global namespace.
At best, you can do :

```
from analyse import vix
```

to put vix into the globals.

(Or use star notation)

Bonus : if you don't want to need analyse installed (even if with venv, it's recommended to actually install your app / module inside a venv), to import `vix` inside `__init__.py`, you can also do a relative import inside :

```
from . import vix
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

**[EDIT] Some examples :**

File system :

```
analyse
 ├─ __init__.py
 ├─ vix.py
 ├─ viz.py # another submodule to demonstrate some other points
 └─ vit.py # yet another submodule to demonstrate some other points
```

`analyse/__init__.py` contains :

```
import .vit as vit
# from . import vit # works too
vix = 42
viy = 43
```

`analyse/vix.py` contains :

```
def draw_vix():
  print('Hello from drax_vix')
```

`analyse/viz.py` contains :

```
def draw_viz():
  print('Hello from drax_viz')
```

`analyse/vit.py` contains :

```
def draw_vit():
  print('Hello from drax_vit')
```

If your package is installed (e.g. you created a setup.py and did `pip install analyse`), or a child of a directory listed in PYTHONPATH env variable, in any script (or the python interpreter) **outside** the package, these things happen :

1) full import with alias :

```
import analyse.vix as vix
vix.draw_vix()
# works, and print print('Hello from drax_vix')
analyse
# Error : analyse not defined since you import only symbols from analyse.vix, not the modules themselves
analyse.vix
# Same as previous one
```

2) Full import

```
import analyse.vix
analyse.vix.draw_vix()
#Works because python guarantees analyse.vix to be a valid expression
analyse
# analyse module
vix.draw_vix()
# Error : vix undefined. import analyse.vix guarantee analyse.vix to be a valid module, but does not add submodule to global namespace
analyse.vix
# is a module, analyse.vix module has been imported too and set as an attribute of analyse.
analyse.viz
# Error : analyse has no attr viz since viz is a non-imported submodule.
analyse.vit.draw_vit
# Works because analyse is indirectly imported with import analyse.vix, and vit is imported as vit inside analyse/__init__.py and thus an attribute of the module.
```

3) Import only analyse

```
import analyse
analyse.vix
# 42 because analyse.vix module is not imported, thus you saw the variable defined vix inside analyse
vix.draw_vix()
# Error : vix undefined, obviously, you never defined it nor imported it
vit.draw_vit()
# Works because vit is imported in __init__.py and set as an attribute of analyse.
```

4) From analyse import vix, viy, viz, vit

```
from analyse import vix, viz, vit
analyse.vix
# Error : analyse not define since you imported only symbols
vix
# 42 Because you didn't import analyse.vix and there is a variable vix defined in analyse/__init__.py
viy
# 43
viz
# module viz : viz is not declared as an attribute of analyse, but it falls back to the existing analyse.viz module
vit
# module vit : The one imported inside __init__.py (that is the same as analyse.vit)
```

5) from analyse import viy

```
from analyse import viy
# Error : analyse/viy.py does not exist
```

Comment: It is no use to write `from analyse import vix`  in `__init__.py`.

Comment: Oh I though he defined a vix symbol inside `analyse.vix` module

Comment: Only inside the analyse module

Comment: `from . import vix` can't work also in `__init__.py`.